# Timer that works across several pages

Tags: php, timer

I am currently working on a Quiz project and I would like to add a timer to it. I have an index page where the user enters Name, Age and Gender and presses start that changes pages to the next one where the first question is. I want the timer to start when Start is pressed.

After doing the questions, when the last one is answered I want the timer to stop and get the time that has passed and possibly save it in a variable that I can use to calculate points based on answers and time passed.

If you can link me to anything, or even give me a direct example that would be great.

Across the pages I am saving the answers in SESSION variables.

tl;dr - I need a timer that starts on Question 1 and stops on Question 4, all questions are on different .php pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$_SESSION` feature to save info across pages.

What you want to do is save the time when the user starts the quizz like this:

```
$_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
```

And in the end, just calculate the current time with the time he started like this:

```
$time_passed = time() - $_SESSION['start_time'];
```

Then you can show it if u want like this:

```
echo date('HH:ii', $time_passed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this would be to store a start time variable on the session. At the end of the quiz, you then compare the start time to the end time to work out the total time spent answering the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

How about when the user clicks on start, you set a session like:

```
$_SESSION['timer'] = time();
```

Then when the user wants to submit the questions, or is on the final page and clicks on the send questions button, you can simply get the current time(); and compare that with $_SESSION['timer'];.

```
$diff = time() - $_SESSION['timer'];
```